# Angular2 router query param chinese garbled

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular2 rc.4 and router 3.0.0-beta.1

When I use router query params  like this :

```
this.router.navigate(['login'],{queryParams:{err:'中国!'}});
```

and loginComponent :

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
    this.router.routerState.queryParams.subscribe(
      params=>{
        this.errMsg=params['err'];
        console.log('errMsg is : '+this.errMsg);
      }
    )
    });
```

If i first open the '/login' page , the console prints :

> "errMsg is 中国"，

**--it shows right .**

**But when I refresh the browser ,  it becomes :**

> "errMsg is : %E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD"

How do I resolve the garbled chinese?

Comment: This sounds like a but in the router itself. Perhaps you can open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, it's simple. use decodeURIComponent function do decode the url param, like this:

```
this.errMsg= decodeURIComponent(params['err']);
```